# Python 3.6.0b4 amd64 - pywin32-220.win-amd64-py3.6 can't find python 3.6-32

Tags: python, pywin32, python-3.6

I just intstalled python 3.6.0b4 (default, Nov 22 2016) amd64 on my Win 7 computer. When I try to install pywin32-220.win-amd64-py3.6 I get the error message `Python version 3.6-32 required, which was not found in the registry`.

Python version 3.6-32 sounds like the 32bit version, which seems inappropriate. Perhaps I misunderstand.

I've seen posts about a similar problem installing pywin 3.5-32, but none relating to 3.6b4 or the 64 bit version.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/731/

I changed LOCAL_MACHINE to CURRENT_USER, although I'm not sure if this matters.  If installing rc1, change b2. Make sure paths are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Simply rename

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.6-32`

To:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.6`

This worked for Python 3.6.1 as well.

Taken from the link above.